# Unnest array of structure in Presto

Tags: arrays, json, presto, complex-data-types

I have the following data in a json format

```
create table events (
id_user bigint,
experiments ARRAY <
    STRUCT <
        id: BIGINT,
        impressed: BOOLEAN,
        variantId: BIGINT
    >
>
)
```

`describe events` returns:

```
columns               | types
id_user               | bigint
experiments           | array(row(id bigint, impressed boolean, variantid bigint))
```

I want to unnest the array struct with the following command

```
select CAST(ROW(array[experiments]) AS ROW(id BIGINT, impressed boolean, variantid bigint)) as test

from events
```

and presto returns the following error:
**failed: the size of fromType and toType must match**

When I enter dummy data in the array the command runs smoothly.

What is the problem and how i overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> presto returns the following error: failed: the size of fromType and toType must match

This:

```
ROW(array[experiments])
```

constructs a `ROW` with one field, of type "`array` of `row`"

> I want to unnest the array

If you want to [`unnest`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) the array, you want something like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(experiments) AS t(experiment) ON true
```

(for older Presto versions use `CROSS JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN .. ON true`; mind that this changes semantics)